# How can I download ReactJS in to Windows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

How can I download ReactJS in to Windows?

I tried [this link](http://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html) but couldn't find the starter kit download option.

I am new to ReactJS, just trying to learn, so can anyone help.

Comment: The website you mentionned suggest the use of npm. Start by [installing it (click here)](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm?utm_source=house&utm_medium=homepage&utm_campaign=free%20orgs&utm_term=Install%20npm)

Comment: Please enter the terms "install" and "reactjs" in your preferred search engine.

Answer (score 0):

click this [refer](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

This a simple library /npm module for creating react app

Comment: `create-react-app` is the best way to get started, it includes a lot of the tooling and config out of the box. You will of course need to have `nodejs` installed on your machine and be able to use the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Reactjs install in windows. [Reference Link](https://makandracards.com/reactjs-quick/52419-install-reactjs-windows)

following this steps:

1. Go to https://nodejs.org/en/
   Download latest version of NodeJS LTS with Administrator privileges.
2. git --version
3. node --version
4. npm --version
5. scoop install yarn ([refrence link](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#windows-stable))
6. npm install webpack -g
7. npm install -g create-react-app
8. create-react-app //projectname//
9. run it : 
    cd //projectname//

   npm start